# Moto G not listed by Qt Creator / adb after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: usb, android, qt, qt-creator, adb

I developed happily with my Moto G on Ubuntu 15.04 a while ago. I upgraded to 15.10 and now that I tested it again Qt Creator (official 5.5 SDK) doesn't see the device anymore.

Developer mode and USB debugging is enabled just like before.

When I plug in the device I get:

```
[ 2490.115388] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=22b8, idProduct=2e76
[ 2490.115402] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2490.115405] usb 1-3: Product: MotoG3
[ 2490.115407] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: motorola
[ 2490.115409] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: ZY2223HN83
```

But:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 

$
```

If I kill the server and start it again I can see the device for a while:

```
$ sudo adb kill-server 
$ sudo adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
ZY2223HN83  device
```

After trying to deploy from Qt Creator (that still doesn't see it) the server goes "out of date":

```
$ adb devices
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
```

Qt Creator shows two(!) ghost devices "ABI is incompatible, device supports ABIs:." in the deploy dialog.

What might cause this? My Qt installation is not changed, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by removing Ubuntu's android-tools-adb and restarting adb server from the Android SDK installation directory.